# Radical requirement: connect a scale to a web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am contemplating creating a web application that will take the reading of scale (i.e. weight measurements) and insert them to a form field. I would like to make this as fluid a process as possible for a user.  Suppose the scale is connected to the computer via a serial port so that the computer can communicate with the scale.

Any ideas on a good setup to achieve this? With a minimal number of clicks by the user? Ideally using a JavaScript ASP.NET setup.

Comment: You will face a similar process to bar code scanners: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435561/reading-from-barcode-scanner and http://www.tec-it.com/en/software/data-acquisition/twedge/keyboard-wedge/Default.aspx

Comment: IMHO, it depends on "how" it communicates with the host. I've dealt with barcode scanners in a past life and at the end of the day, it ended up being a "keyboard"-like interface. Scan barcode/UPC -> send to host as text -> to any "client application" (it could be notepad, or a form input field on a web app or windows form). Once data is in "your app" you take it from there..Hth...

Comment: I have done this for our in-house use.  I use Google Chrome Apps because it exposes the serial and or USB port to the web browser.  That being said, I have a very limited set of users but it works well for me. [Here is one link giving an example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/serial/ledtoggle/main.js)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the end user should install some software that will work with the hardware device. Because your web application can be used on many different platforms then you should find/develop software for each platform and suggest users to install and configure this software.

Yes, if you'll limit your users by the Windows platform then you may use any keyboard wedge or data logging software. One more:

http://www.aggsoft.com/serial-data-logger/